# Cannot install Ubuntu on Asus X552E because of weird graphics

Tags: ati, graphics, asus

I have bought an Asus X552E, AMD A4 with Radeon HD 8670M gpu. I want to install ubuntu 14.04 on it but I have a strange problem. when I start installing, the LCD of laptop encounters with graphical problems. it shows the screen in pixel pixel format as if the gpu is out of order! but when I reboot the laptop and use Win 8.1, there is no graphical problem in the screen!

I have checked the gpu in support of Asus in my country, they told me this chip is fine and maybe the ubuntu is havibg conflict on AMD or Radeon gpu!

Can anybody help please?

So , this is what it looks like when I try to boot live USB. Also, I've tried Ubuntu 13 and same thing occurs.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiaVa.jpg)

Edit: I've posted it 20 days ago, still nothing. Can't find the solution.

Comment: I've finally solved it with the new version of Ubuntu 14.10. !

Answer (score 0):

try to set your BIOS settings to default and try it again.
It looks like a GPU issue, that is true, but it can be bcs of Asus BIOS settings, 
some turbo mode or similar. Report the progress!

EDIT: When you boot the Live CD, navigate to

System Settings->Software & Upgrades->Additional Drivers.

Wait few seconds to find your hardware and check for appropriate driver, install them and then try to run your installation. I never tried it, its only a hint but maybe it will work.

Comment: BTW: Lijepi pozdrav iz Medimurja ;)